# Accessing client side objects and code

Tags: apache-spark

A Spark applications needs to validate each element in an RDD.

Given a driver\client side Scala object called `Validator`, which of the following two solutions is better:

```
rdd.filter { x => if Validator.isValid(x.somefield) true else false }
```

or something like

```
// get list of the field to validate against
val list = rdd.map(x => x.somefield)
// Use the Validator to check which ones are invalid
var invalidElements = Validator.getValidElements().diff(list)
// remove invalid elements from the RDD
rdd.filter(x => !invalidElements.contains(x.somefield))
```

The second solution avoids referencing the driver side object from within the function passed to the RDD. The invalid elements are determined on the client, that list is then passed back to the RDD.

Or is neither recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (i.e. you have an `object Validator`), that's not driver code, because your job's Jar will also be distributed to the workers. So a Scala object you define will also be instantiated in the executor JVM. (That's also why you don't receive a serialization exception in contrast to using methods defined in the job, e.g. in Spark Streaming with checkpointing).

The first version should perform better because you filter first. Mapping over all of the data and then filtering it will be slower.

The second version is also problematic because if you are creating a list of valid elements on the driver, you now have to ship it back to the workers.

Comment: There may be an issue if the Validator object is pushed to each worker, because it will contain a cache which is maintained dynamically. That has to be a singleton.

Comment: Ok, but that's a different issue then that you did not specify in your question.

Comment: What is the best way to architect for that scenario Marius? Thanks

Comment: Marius, thanks for your help. Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385480/packaging-client-side-code-to-pass-to-an-rdd

Comment: You should include your specific requirement in the question - i.e. you want a global variable that is shared across the nodes. It would also be nice of you to accept this answer if helped so far.

Comment: Answer accepted, thanks very much, New question on global variables is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401537/global-variables-in-spark