# Packaging client side code to pass to an RDD

Tags: apache-spark

A scala function is passed into `rdd.map()`. The logic is too complex to be included within the function itself, and instead the logic is encapsulated within a scala `object`. The object is part of the application which instantiates the Spark context, as in the following example:

```
def func(s.String) = {
   // LogicEngine is object which, given a string, returns a different string
   LogicEngine.process(s) 
}

val sc = new SparkContext(config)

val rdd = sc.textFile(“…”)

val rdd2 = rdd.map(func)
```

The question is, what is the correct way to do this so that `LogicEngine` is itself passed to the nodes on which the rdd itself is being processed (so that it lives together with the function code passed to the rdd), rather than sitting on the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you have already. Each node will instantiate and use its own copy of `LogicEngine` when it's first accessed.

Comment: Thanks. Going one step further: if LogicEngine has an internal, static lookup list it uses, presumably that will be passed to the node together with the code. But what if LogicEngine uses a dynamic list which grows as rdd's are processed. Will each node only see the cache in the state it was when first passed to the rdd?

Comment: See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables.

Comment: Just to clarify that my understanding is correct - to implement a global variable - in this case a cache - which will be updated dynamically (by the nodes themselves) and shared across all nodes, we should use an Accumulator.

Comment: @user1052610 Accumulators can't be _read_ by the nodes (but can be updated), and Broadcasts can't be _modified_ (but can be read). Spark simply doesn't have global state which can be both read and modified (AFAIK).

Comment: How then would one implement a global cache which would not be static? Would it be possible with Spark? Presumably, if the cache sat on the client, performance would be poor.

Comment: You have to obtain this cache by transformations from other RDDs instead of thinking in terms of mutation. Alternately, cheat and use some other framework to communicate with the cache, but first think how much of a bottleneck this cache will be, what happens if a transformation needs to be rerun, etc. "Presumably, if the cache sat on the client, performance would be poor." Yes, that's _why_ Spark doesn't allow it.